# Java - Null Pointer Exception, but I can get the value

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null, getter-setter

So I wrote a program and there are 3 NPEs - I can't see why, maybe I'm blind from my flu ;) Could anybody tell me what's wrong?

I don't paste whole code, but only important classes. The rest is ok.

```
package maszyna;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    User user = new User(); // first NPE
    Mode.start = true;
    Mode.pause = false; 

    Machine machine = new Machine();
    user.addListener(machine);       


    user.setTimeStart("1:15:30");
    //System.out.println("It's " +user.getTimeStart()); // but I can see this
    user.setTimePause("1:15:40");//when it's uncommented ofc
    user.setTimeResume("1:15:50");
    user.setTimeRestart("1:16:00");
    user.setTimeStop("1:16:10");



}
}
```

And here's class User:

```
package maszyna;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.*;



public class User{

    String name;
    String timeStart;
    String timeStop;
    String timePause;
    String timeResume;
    String timeRestart;
    String[] temp = new String[3];    
    int[] SMTi = new int[3];
    private List<UserListener> listeners;

           Thread life = new Thread(){
            @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(Mode.start==true){

                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();     
                        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            machineStart(hour, minute, second);
            machineStop(hour, minute, second);
            machinePause(hour, minute, second);
                            machineResume(hour, minute, second);
                            machineRestart(hour, minute, second);

            try {
                sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

};

    public User(){    
      this.listeners = new ArrayList<UserListener>();
    life.start();
    }   



public String getTimeStart() {
    return timeStart;
}

public void setTimeStart(String timeStart) {
    this.timeStart = timeStart;
}

public String getTimeStop() {
    return timeStop;
}

public void setTimeStop(String timeStop) {
    this.timeStop = timeStop;
}

public String getTimePause() {
    return timePause;
}

public void setTimePause(String timePause) {
    this.timePause = timePause;
}

public String getTimeResume() {
    return timeResume;
}

public void setTimeResume(String timeResume) {
    this.timeResume = timeResume;
}

public String getTimeRestart() {
    return timeRestart;
}

public void setTimeRestart(String timeRestart) {
    this.timeRestart = timeRestart;
}

    int[] tStart = splitMyTime(getTimeStart()); //they are set, aren't they?
    int[] tPause = splitMyTime(getTimePause()); //I can get them in Main when I want to
    int[] tResume = splitMyTime(getTimeResume());
    int[] tRestart = splitMyTime(getTimeRestart());
    int[] tStop = splitMyTime(getTimeStop());



public int[] splitMyTime(String cos){

    if(cos==null){ //I made this if for tests
        System.out.println("OMG, it's null"); //it displays OMG 5 times
        int[] kot = {1, 2, 3};//and part below throws NPE, when if is hidden in comment
        Mode.start = false;
        return kot;
    }
    else{ // and this part causes NPE
    temp = cos.split(":|.");    
int l = temp.length;    
for(int a=0; a<l; a++){
SMTi[a] = Integer.parseInt(temp[a]); //NPE, when I just write the arguments above instead getters
    }

return SMTi;
    }
 }



public synchronized void addListener(UserListener listener)
{
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public synchronized void removeListener(UserListener listener)
{
    listeners.remove(listener);
}


protected synchronized void machineStart(int hour, int minute, int second)
{                  

            if(second == tStart[2] && 
                    minute == tStart[1] &&
                    hour == tStart[0]){


    System.out.println("START \n \n");        


    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent(this);

    for(UserListener ul: listeners)
    {
        ul.machineStart(ue);
    }
            }
}


    protected synchronized void machineStop(int hour, int minute, int second)
{               
           if(second == tStop[2] && 
                    minute == tStop[1] &&
                    hour == tStop[0]){
    System.out.println("STOP \n \n");
    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent(this);
    for(UserListener ul: listeners)
    {
        ul.machineStop(ue);
    }
            }
}


    protected synchronized void machinePause(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
            if(second == tPause[2] && 
                    minute == tPause[1] &&
                    hour == tPause[0]){
    System.out.println("PAUSE \n \n");
            Mode.pause = true;
    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent(this);
    for(UserListener ul: listeners)
    {
        ul.machinePause(ue);
    }
            }
}


    protected synchronized void machineResume(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
            if(second == tResume[2] && 
                    minute == tResume[1] &&
                    hour == tResume[0]){
    System.out.println("RESUME \n \n");
            Mode.pause = false;
    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent(this);
    for(UserListener ul: listeners)
    {
        ul.machineResume(ue);
    }
            }
}


    protected synchronized void machineRestart(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
        if(second == tRestart[2] && 
                    minute == tRestart[1] &&
                    hour == tRestart[0]){
    System.out.println("RESTART \n \n");
    UserEvent ue = new UserEvent(this);
    for(UserListener ul: listeners)
    {
        ul.machineRestart(ue);
    }
        }
}


}
```

I tried to reorganize the parts of code, but it didn't help. I don't know what's going on. I need someone outside to look freshly at that. Thanks a lot.

You wanted stack trace, here it is :)

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at maszyna.User.splitMyTime(User.java:110)
at maszyna.User.<init>(User.java:93)
at maszyna.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post a stack trace.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I'm not sure. I can't reproduce a NPE with a mock-up I've tried. The OP needs to produce and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: How much more code do you have? Your current code does not reproduce the NPE.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it's easier if you read the code: `if (cos == null) { ... } else { temp = cos.split(":|."); //naive NPE`

Comment: I made this if/else, when I've seen there's a problem here. I thought "ok, so you tell me it's null here, let's check it" - and it is indeed. So where I should initialize the values to be sure the'yre not null? And, as I said, when I replace getTimeSomething() with string like "12:12:12", it tells me there is NPE on parseInt line.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: but it won't be null in the else block, only in the if block, only if the if condition is true.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, looks like I read the code too fast. Re-reading it.

Comment: The only explanation I could get is that you're not running the code you're looking at. Try rebuilding your project and running it again.

Comment: There's more code than he is showing us. If the rest of the program is not too large, then post it. Otherwise create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your StackTrace you could do these steps:

A) Change your attributes' initialization like this:

```
int[] tStart = null; 
int[] tPause = null;
int[] tResume = null;
int[] tRestart = null;
int[] tStop = null;
```

B) Add a method to split your times:

```
public void splitAllTimes() {
    this.tStart = splitMyTime(getTimeStart()); 
    this.tPause = splitMyTime(getTimePause()); 
    this.tResume = splitMyTime(getTimeResume());
    this.tRestart = splitMyTime(getTimeRestart());
    this.tStop = splitMyTime(getTimeStop());
}
```

C) Change your main method to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    User user = new User(); 
    Mode.start = true;
    Mode.pause = false; 

    Machine machine = new Machine();
    user.addListener(machine);       


    user.setTimeStart("1:15:30");
    user.setTimePause("1:15:40");
    user.setTimeResume("1:15:50");
    user.setTimeRestart("1:16:00");
    user.setTimeStop("1:16:10");
    //------------------Add this line--------------------
    user.splitAllTimes();  //Add this line to init your attrbutes
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice was very helpful. It works now. I also cleaned up a mess in my code, as I was suggested before.